# Format balance availablefrom facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to get the balance that a facebook ad account has positive or negative, however, I am following the facebook documentation and the same says that the field is "balance", below I am putting the print taken from the facebook documentation.

[image]

I'm getting this value according to the documentation the problem is that I don't know how to format the value correctly, the value is coming without a decimal separator, has anyone been there?
How do I know when to format the value with decimal or not?

Below is the printout of my return that I'm getting from the API.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider the AdAccounts currency offset, as [described here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/currencies), as a static table:

> ### Offset
>
> Each currency has an offset which specifies how Facebook should handle
> its sub-divisions. This is to ensure that the minimum bid, such as
> "1", is a usable value for the currency.
>
> ### Example offset 100
>
> If a currency has an offset of 100 then the minimum allowed bid is
> assumed to be 1/100 of the currency base unit. For example, if you
> place a bid of "1" on an ad account based on USD the bid will be 0.01
> USD.
>
> ### Example offset 1
>
> If a currency has an offset of 1 then the minimum allowed bid is
> assumed to be in the currency base unit. For example, if you place a
> bid of "1" on a ad account based on JPY the bid will be 1 JPY.

A sample of the table:

| Name | Code | Offset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Algerian Dinar | DZD | 100 |
| Argentine Peso | ARS | 100 |
| .. | .. | .. |
| Brazilian Real | BRL | 100 |
| .. | .. | .. |
| Chilean Peso | CLP | 1 |
| .. | .. | .. |

So for your currency you should consider an offset of 100.

Comment: Excellent, it solved my problem, thank you.